# Which cue did Thomas Newman orchestrate in Return of the Jedi?

Tags: star-wars, behind-the-scenes, return-of-the-jedi, music, composition

In a [*When John Williams Can't Go*](https://www.npr.org/2015/10/17/449417429/composer-thomas-newman-teams-with-spielberg-for-bridge-of-spies) article I found:

> And just as Alfred Newman gave John Williams some of his first big breaks, Williams, in turn, gave Thomas Newman one of his first plum assignments as a Hollywood musician.
>
> "He threw me a bone. I mean, he would not put it that way. But **he let me orchestrate a cue from Return of the Jedi, *when Darth Vader dies***," Newman says, then laughs: "It was an amazing thing to do."

I was wondering if this cue was exactly the one playing when [Luke takes off Vader's mask](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TNDwCsFzS8c). Any way of confirming this through other references or sources?

Comment: Well he died in that scene so assuming the article you link isn't false then yes it is that one. Everything else points to it being true but not much is really sourced

Comment: FWIW he appears to be uncredited for the film so it will likely be hard to prove/disprove.

Comment: My thought was that it might be the tragic rendition of the Imperial motif at the end of the scene as Vader breathes his last breath.

Comment: related info re: orchestration vs composition - http://www.composingcomposer.com/composition-vs-orchestration-part-1/

Comment: Fred Steiner (also known for Star Trek TOS) was involved as well - https://www.loc.gov/item/jots.200025862/

Comment: As @TheLethalCarrot says, pretty much every thing points to it being true, although Williams is credited as saying in a couple interviews that the score was pretty much done and his involvement was 'minimal'.